# Using a Database Trigger to move a record

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

I am new to the use of Database triggers so I want to get pointed in the right direction here. I would like to make a trigger to execute on 'insert' of new Invoice or 'Update' of 'BalanceDue' of my `Invoice` table to take the `VendorID` in `Invoices`, Grab the `Vendor` row in the `Vendors` table and move some data from that row to another table for `ShippingLabels`. This is what I got so far but Im kinda at a loss for where to go from here.

```
CREATE TRIGGER trSetShippingLabels
ON tblInvoices
AFTER Insert, Update
AS
INSERT INTO tblShippingLabels
SELECT VendorName, VendorAddress, VendorCity, VendorState, VendorZipCode
FROM tblVendors
JOIN tblInvoices i on i.VendorID = Vendors.VendorID
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're pretty close. You just need to use [the special "inserted" table](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191300%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) within your trigger. This table is accessible within triggers (or in conjunction with the output clause), and holds all the data inserted by the last statement executed against the relevant permanent table. There is also a corresponding "deleted" table if you wanted to remove some data in a trigger.

```
CREATE TRIGGER trSetShippingLabels
ON tblInvoices
AFTER Insert,Update
AS
INSERT INTO tblShippingLabels
SELECT VendorName, VendorAddress, VendorCity, VendorState, VendorZipCode
FROM Vendors
JOIN Inserted i on i.VendorID = Vendors.VendorID
```

Comment: I knew about the inserted thing but wasnt sure if that would work with updates too.

Comment: @AndyLink It does. From the MSDN link: `An update transaction is similar to a delete operation followed by an insert operation; the old rows are copied to the deleted table first, and then the new rows are copied to the trigger table and to the inserted table.`